# Update query where set statement gets value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

SQL Server 2008 R2

Table CIRTB

```
CIRLogID PrimaryKey
StaffName
StaffID
```

Table StaffTB

```
StaffID - PrimaryKey
Fullname
DOB
CIN
Program
```

I have `StaffID`'s in the `CIRTB` table that are Null, so I need to update it from the `Staff` table.

I know I need something like the following

```
update CIRTB
set CIRTB>staffid = (select staffid 
                     from stafftb 
                     where stafftb.fullname = cirtb.Staffname)
where CIRTB.staffid is null
```

One problem that I am stuck on: there are some duplicates in the `StaffTB` for fullname, dob, program

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do the `UPDATE` is using a `CTE`:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT t1.StaffID AS t1_StaffID, t2.StaffID AS t2_StaffID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Fullname 
                             ORDER BY t2.DOB DESC) AS rn
   FROM CIRTB AS t1
   JOIN StaffTB AS t2 ON t1.StaffName = t2.Fullname
   WHERE t1.StaffID IS NULL
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET t1_StaffID = t2_StaffID
WHERE rn = 1
```

The `CTE` uses `ROW_NUMBER` in order to pick one record per `Fullname`. The `ORDER BY` clause of the window function determines which record is picked in case of duplicates: since `DOB DESC` is used, the record having the most recent `DOB` is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Use TOP 1 in the sub-select to make sure it only returns one row even if there are duplicates.